# Se pueden hacer un numero variable de bucles for anidados?

Tags: python

La duda va así, estoy aprendiendo **Python** y quise hacer algo similar al "hackeo por fuerza bruta". El problema es que la contraseña puede tener un numero variable de caracteres, y por cada carácter de largo quiero tener un for anidado. Intenté esto, siendo que por cada carácter hago un a.append(), chars[] viene de un archivo de texto donde pongo los caracteres que admite (si es solo numérico, números y letras, etc.)

```
for a[0] in chars[0]:
  for a[1] in chars[0]:
    for a[2] in chars[0]:
        for a[3] in chars[0]:
            for a[4] in chars[0]:
                for a[5] in chars[0]:
                    for a[6] in chars[0]:
                        for a[7] in chars[0]:
```

La duda en resumen es esa, como hago que haya ***x*** fors anidados siguiendo esta estructura, y que dependiendo una variable cambie el numero de fors

Comment: No puedes hacer un número indeterminado de `for` pero puedes hacer una función que contenga un bucle `for` así cada vez que requieras una iteravion llamas a la función

Comment: No me queda claro que `for` anidados sea la mejor manera de hacer lo que pretendes. No si la pregunta a) es como probar todas las combinaciones o b) Como anidar un número variable de `for`.

Comment: No puedes hacer o crear bucles for como tu mencionas, creo que lo que tratas de hacer seria mejor hacerlo con una función además de que lo anterior creo también haría tu programa mas optimo. O por lo menos yo desconozco como hacer lo que pides si es posible.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Para generar todas las claves posibles puedes recurrir al módulo `itertools`, que contiene funciones generales para manejar iterables.

Una función útil es `combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)`. Esta función toma un iterable (una cadena, una lista, etc.) y retorna todas las combinaciones posibles de largo `r`. Cada combinación está compuesta de elementos del iterable, los que pueden repetirse.

El programa queda así:

```
import itertools

chars = "AEIOU1234567890"

for clave in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 3):
    print(''.join(clave))
```

Probe sólo cadenas de largo tres, para acortar la historia, pero funciona igual con cualquier largo que pongas.

La función retorna tuplas, donde cada elemento es una letra. Usamos `join` para juntar todas las letras y producir una clave.

**Resultado**

```
AAA
AAE
AAI
AAO
AAU
...
...
...
800
999
990
900
000
```